# Stacking order of elements affected by opacity

Tags: css, z-index

How are `z-index` and `opacity` related when deciding stacking order of an element in HTML?

when i keep `opacity` less than `1` on an element which is having some `z-index` say `999`. The element is going behind the element which is having no `z-index`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox1").on("change", function() {
    $("#green-parent").toggleClass("add-opacity", this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.green,
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.green {
  z-index: 999999999;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
  background: blue;
}
.add-opacity {
  opacity: 0.99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="checkbox1">Add opacity to green box parent</label>


<div id="green-parent">
  <span class="green">Green</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="blue">Blue</span>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML and CSS are two completely different things. Don't conflate the two. This question is about CSS, as correctly stated in the tags.

Comment: `opacity` less than 1 creates new stacking context. See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I dont really understand your question or problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positioned elements with a z-index value other than "auto" and elements with an opacity value less than 1 generate a stacking context. Refer to the [rules regarding the painting order](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#painting-order).

In your first example we have the root stacking context with various descendants including:

- positioned green box with positive z-index
- positioned blue box with `auto` z-index

The blue box with `auto` z-index is placed behind; green box with positive z-index is placed in front (see rule no. 8 and 9).

In your second example we have:

- an element with opacity (which contains green box; note that z-index on the green box becomes local to this element)
- positioned blue box without z-index

Both elements fall under same category (see rule no. 8). In which case the HTML order determines which element appear in front. The blue box appears later in the source order so it appears in front.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the [`opacity` stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) Alexey Ten pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185273/stacking-order-in-html/30185361#comment48475820_30185273) (which is a factor here), the `z-index` is relative to the element's container. In this case, both your blue and green elements are contained within separate `div` parents which have no defined `z-index`. Due to the HTML ordering, the latter `div` (the one with the blue box) will appear on top of the former one (the green one).

In this below example, I've added the class `.first` to the first parent `div` and `.second` to the second one, then given them their own `z-index` properties.

```css
.green, .blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.green {
  z-index:999999999;
  top: 90px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
.gp{
  opacity:0.99;
}
.blue {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.first, .second {
  position: relative;
}

.first {
  z-index: 2;
}

.second {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <span class="green">Green</span>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <span class="blue">Blue</span>
</div>
```