# Z-index is causing incorrect stacking

Tags: css, z-index

I have a calendar at the following page:

http://www.plumgrid.com/calendar/category/events/2016-03/?tribe_events_cat=events&tribe-bar-date=2016-03

When we mouseover the event on March 2nd "OpenStack Meetup | Washington, DC", the popup goes behind the header banner image.

I have looked into the z-index and the opacity, and tried to figure out whats going wrong in terms of stacking order and context but cannot find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with opacity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185273/stacking-order-of-elements-affected-by-opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you have an overflow hidden on the div with id "main"

So even with a z-index, the div is hidden when outside the box (try commenting the line 7743 of style.css)

Comment: This is the line: `.tribe-filter-live #main { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: Thank you so much Aziz - sometimes the mind gets totally stuck at generating ideas.

Answer (score 2):

For `z-index` to have any effect on stacking, the element should have the attribute `position` to `relative` or `absolute`.